# What Does this << Statement Mean?

Tags: c

I am working on a simple project in C where I encountered this statement in one of the tutorials.

```
int i = 1 << 2 ;
```

What does this statement actually do?

Comment: It is bit shift operator. Google it please. Period.

Comment: it is a 'shift' operator.

Comment: you should read THE book first.

Comment: [Bitwise Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Left_shift_.3C.3C)

Comment: It is the bitwise left shift operator. In your case it does the same thing as this: `int i = 1 * 4 ;` which can be simplified to `int i = 4 ;`

Answer (score 2):

This is also called the shift operator. It will shift de bits n positions to the left. Shifting the bits by one positions is the same as multiplying or dividing by 2.

Answer (score 2):

It is a left-shift operator.

It applies on the bit representation of 1 and shift it's bits to left by 2 position.

Answer (score 0):

Shift left is a bitwise operation.
Look here: [Bitwise operations in C wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C)

Answer (score 0):

`<<` is a binary Left Shift operator. The left operands value is shifted left by the number of bits specified by the right operand. and `0` are padded in the right. So the binary of `1` i.e, `1` is shifted left 2 places and becomes `100` which is `4` in decimal number system. So `i` is assigned `4`.

[Here is a quick tutorial that explains bitwise operations](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_operators.htm)